# *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Tags: ios, json, google-maps

When I run this code it says that : 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

I think that the problem is that, it tries to fetch the info from here : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json? but it is not able to perform that action due to the non availability of the parameters : origin=LosAngeles&destination=Texas&sensor=false

## The question :

How to make *jsonURL attached (concatenated with) to *post, in order to obtain the full link in the background and process it : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=LosAngeles&destination=Texas&sensor=false
but keeping the same structure (divided in that way).

Comment: Why do you set `post` like that??  Why not just assign `@"origin=LosAngeles&destination=Texas&sensor=false"` to it directly?

Comment: And where is the exception occurring?  There is no NSArray in the above code segment.

Comment: (Do you know how to get the exception traceback?)

Comment: because I want to set dynamic parameters to orgin and destination ?

Comment: How does the above statement accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the parameters be part of the URL, you need to have the parameters be part of the string you pass to `URLWithString:`.